# Python wkhtmltopdf can't import module

Tags: python, django-wkhtmltopdf

I am using Python version 3.6, Django version 1.9 and wkhtmltopdf version 0.2. My Python is not GCC it's Anaconda3.

When running my project which uses `wkhtmltopdf`, following error will be thrown:

```
from main import WKhtmlToPdf, wkhtmltopd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

This is how I imported the wkhtmltopdf:

```
import pdfkit
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView
```

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533177/no-module-named-main-wkhtmltopdf-issue/63240540

Answer (score 3):

Yes i got the answer. This error occurred because i didn't installed django-wkhtmltopdf.
installed >> `pip install django-wkhtmltopdf

I hope this answer will help to resolve the similar error.

Comment: Did not help. Got both wkhtmltopdf and django-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 2):

after installing pdfkit with following command and pointing python version 3.8, i was able to get pdfkit working on mac

```
pip3 install pdfkit
```