# generate table of contents with pdfkit for python

Tags: python, pdf, xslt, pdfkit, tableofcontents

**Summary of problem:** I cannot get the table of contents generator to work in pdfkit for Python.

**What I have tried:** Passing argument `toc`.

**My current code:**

```
toc = {'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc.xsl'}

pdfkit.from_file(
    book_html_filename, book_pdf_filename, 
    configuration=config, 
    toc=toc,
    options=options,cover=cover_html_filename,cover_first=True)
```

I am not familiar with `.xsl` at all, and therefore I don't know for example what should go into that file.

My current `.xsl` file:

I mean it is empty. I get the following error message:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[===>                                                        ] 5%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[==================>                                         ] 30%
[=================================>                          ] 55%
[=============================================>              ] 75%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[===================>                                        ] Object 1 of 3
[============================================================] Object 3 of 3
Error XTSE0010 in file:///C:/Program%20Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe, at line 1, column 0: Parse error: Premature end of document.
Loading TOC (3/6)                                                           
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[============================================================] 100%
Error XTSE0010 in file:///C:/Program%20Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe, at line 1, column 0: Parse error: Premature end of document.
[======>                                                     ] 10% 
[============================================================] 100%
Resolving links (4/6)                                              
[===================>                                        ] Object 1 of 3
[=======================================>                    ] Object 2 of 3
[============================================================] Object 3 of 3
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[========>                                                   ] Page 1 of 7
[================>                                           ] Page 2 of 7
[=========================>                                  ] Page 3 of 7
[==================================>                         ] Page 4 of 7
[==========================================>                 ] Page 5 of 7
[===================================================>        ] Page 6 of 7
[============================================================] Page 7 of 7
Done                                                                      
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\SeferMaker\py\create_pdf_with_pdfkit.py", line 40, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_file(
```

Comment: did you install wkhtmltopdf on your machine?

Comment: yes, definitely. the pdf is produced, just fails when i try to add the table of contents.